# Mount Windows Sever (2012) smb1 on Ubuntu (18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, samba, smb, cifs

I am trying to mount our SMB shared Raid with /etc/fstab with very little luck.
(The raid is a Tiger Technology raid, from appx 2015, running what I believe Windows Server 2012, we don't have access to the windows part of the raid, that is locked by Tiger Tech.)

I'm able to mount a newer QNAP smb mount and a Windows 7 mount with fstab, no problem.

Tiger Tech sendt these instructions,

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=1.0 //10.0.0.50/Tmount /mnt/Tmount
```

Resulting in a

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Tried similar commands in /etc/fstab using the "guest" argument, with same results

I also have a username and password that works, made a .smbcerdentials file with username, pass and domain. Still no go, but some progress atleast. Now I don't get any errors using "mount -a".
But when I go to /mnt/Tmount and "ls", I get the error

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

And the log gave no error, last log entry in /var/log/syslog was

```
CIFS: Attempting to mount
```

We also have two other Tiger Raids on different locations, and two identical Ubuntu 18.04 machines (clean Ubuntu install with docker installed) running on those locations.

here I can get the SMB mount to work with

```
//10.0.0.50/Tmount /mnt/Tmount cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I can mount the problematic mount in Windows, Mac OS and Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.
I can also use

```
smblcient //10.0.0.50/Tmount -N
```

And it works, same with "-U user pass", I can mount, list files etc.

Seems I can mount this mount everywhere, except where I need it.
Any tips to how to auto mount this raid during boot?

Thanks!

Edit 1:
I experimented with an emergency solution, Tiger provides software to mount the raid to pc/mac. And gives the mount a drive letter.
I shared two folders from the test Windows 7 machine, a test folder from the C: drive, and another folder from the T: drive (raid mount)

The temp folder on C: works fine, the folder from T: drive give same error

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

But In windows the T: drive behaves as any other drive.

Edit 2: After further trial, I noticed, while I get

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

when trying to list the content of the share, I can sudo mkdir, and it works. So what stops the ls command?

Comment: Try upgrading the package associated with mount.cifs

Comment: Would that be cifs-utils? apt-cache policy cifs-utils, gives: 
 cifs-utils:
  Installed: 2:6.8-1ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2:6.8-1ubuntu1.1